Create column based off the most recent last values of 2 other columns
Background
I have a dataframe of stock prices and am trying to build a trading entry signal. The logic is to enter position one day after whenever there is a Trigger with a stop loss signal "Exit"
Because once there has been an Entry I will hold the position until stopped out, a new Entry (except the first) can only occur once there has been an Exit after the previous Entry. (e.g. 2 Entries cannot happen without an Exit in between)
Problem
I am having trouble how to create Entry signals in column "signal 3" to uniquely capture only real Entry (Trigger day after if there has been an Exit after the previous Entry).
Below dataframe is what I am working with:
Date         Price  Trigger   signal 3   Stop Loss
2024-03-06  9540.0  NaN          NaN    NaN
2024-03-07  10270.0 NaN          NaN    NaN
2024-03-08  8120.0  Trigger      NaN    NaN
2024-03-11  6620.0  NaN          Entry  NaN
2024-03-12  5620.0  NaN          NaN    NaN
2024-03-13  6620.0  NaN          NaN    Exit
2024-03-14  5930.0  NaN          NaN    NaN
...
2024-03-22  7120.0  Trigger      NaN    NaN
2024-03-28  6090.0  NaN          Entry  NaN
2024-03-29  5680.0  Trigger      NaN    NaN
2024-04-01  5340.0  NaN          NaN    NaN
2024-04-02  4885.0  NaN          NaN    NaN

As per example above the last Trigger should not result in an entry since the Trigger before that lead to an Entry but no Exit was defined.
Right now I am only using a for loop to iterate through every single row with a variable called position that increments to 1 whenever entry is made and resets to 0 when exit is made but given this is a dataframe there must be a vectorized faster solution.

can you provide your expected output?

You can compute two boolean mask with help of fillna+ffill+shift:
# is the previous row a Trigger?
m1 = df['Trigger'].shift().eq('Trigger')

# was there an Exit/start before the previous Trigger?
m2 = (df['Trigger'].fillna(df['Stop Loss'])
      .ffill().shift(2).ne('Trigger')
     )

df.loc[m1&m2, 'signal 3'] = 'Entry'

Output:
          Date    Price  Trigger signal 3 Stop Loss
0   2024-03-06   9540.0      NaN      NaN       NaN
1   2024-03-07  10270.0      NaN      NaN       NaN
2   2024-03-08   8120.0  Trigger      NaN       NaN
3   2024-03-11   6620.0      NaN    Entry       NaN
4   2024-03-12   5620.0      NaN      NaN       NaN
5   2024-03-13   6620.0      NaN      NaN      Exit
6   2024-03-14   5930.0      NaN      NaN       NaN
7   2024-03-22   7120.0  Trigger      NaN       NaN
8   2024-03-28   6090.0      NaN    Entry       NaN
9   2024-03-29   5680.0  Trigger      NaN       NaN
10  2024-04-01   5340.0      NaN      NaN       NaN
11  2024-04-02   4885.0      NaN      NaN       NaN

Intermediates:
          Date    Price  Trigger signal 3 Stop Loss     m1     m2  m1&m2
0   2024-03-06   9540.0      NaN      NaN       NaN  False   True  False
1   2024-03-07  10270.0      NaN      NaN       NaN  False   True  False
2   2024-03-08   8120.0  Trigger      NaN       NaN  False   True  False
3   2024-03-11   6620.0      NaN    Entry       NaN   True   True   True
4   2024-03-12   5620.0      NaN      NaN       NaN  False  False  False
5   2024-03-13   6620.0      NaN      NaN      Exit  False  False  False
6   2024-03-14   5930.0      NaN      NaN       NaN  False  False  False
7   2024-03-22   7120.0  Trigger      NaN       NaN  False   True  False
8   2024-03-28   6090.0      NaN    Entry       NaN   True   True   True
9   2024-03-29   5680.0  Trigger      NaN       NaN  False  False  False
10  2024-04-01   5340.0      NaN      NaN       NaN   True  False  False
11  2024-04-02   4885.0      NaN      NaN       NaN  False  False  False

Alternatively, using numba:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def signal(trigger, exit):
    flag = True
    entry = False
    for t, e in zip(trigger, exit):
        yield entry
        if entry:
            entry = False
            flag = False
        if e:
            flag = True
        if t and flag:
            entry = True

df.loc[signal(df['Trigger'].eq('Trigger').to_numpy(),
              df['Stop Loss'].eq('Exit').to_numpy()),
       'signal 3'] = 'Entry'

timing
On 1.2M rows:
# vectorized pandas
296 ms ± 27.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# numba
221 ms ± 8.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

